# Riemann integration question

Tags: real-analysis

A practice question for my analysis midterm is as follows:

Give an example of a function $f:[a, b] \to\ \mathbb R$ such that $f \in R[a, c] \forall c \in\ [a, b)$ but $$f \notin R[a, b]$$

I can't think of any examples.  Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take $f$ to be unbounded "at $b$".

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}\frac1{1-x}&\mathrm{if}&x\in[0,1)\\0&\mathrm{if}&x=1\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Would you mind elaborating why this works?  What is the value of c in this case?  I assume a=0 and b=1.

Comment: "What is the value of c in this case?" Please refer to your own post: here, the condition "$\forall c \in\ [a, b)$" means "for every $0\leqslant c\lt1$".

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function f(x) = 1/(1 - x) on [0, 1]. You can assign f(1) = any number.

Comment: But this is undefined at 1.